# Selenium IDE : i have some problems with copying some elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

This is my first time to ask a question! (excited!!!)

But i don't have enough reputations to post a image...

i'm trying to use selenium to automatically upload the image and get the result on how-old.net

And after uploading the image, there will be a button "View Source"

So after i clicked "View Source", the JSON part would come out. But i fail to copy that part of element. And although i recorded the behavior of click "View Source", that JSON part doesn't show up when i run the recording in selenium ide. Anyone knows why? THX!

Comment: By copy do you mean the IDE fails to record?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot copy text to the clipboard using Selenium IDE. However, if you want to use the JSON in the textarea later in the script, you can use `storeText` to save it in a variable:

[image: Selenium IDE Screenshot]

The command is `storeText(locator, variableName)`. You can use the variable "the_source" later as `${the_source}`

As for your other question: with `typeAndWait` it works for me, you probably forgot the `AndWait` part that waits for the triggered request to finish.

Comment: Thanks! But does it work for you to print out the variable? I stored the text but the variable is empty.